# Is there anyway nested xib with another xib file?

Tags: nested, xib

What I want to do, I have a UIView with UIToolbar via IB, and the UIToolbar is customized via IB, what I want to set is set the UIToolbar by xib file, not load from source?

is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `UIToolbar` in UIView XIB-file.
2. Change class of UIToolbar from UIToolbar to MyCustomToolbarSubclass(choose yours subclass) in IB.

It's important to have this MyCustomToolbarSubclass for your custom UIToolbar. And you have to declare parent as UIToolbar. Change Object, UIViewController or anything you choose as parent class when create new class for your UIToolbar.

Also there are too many [solves](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=custom%20uitoolbar) any problems with custom toolbars. It helps me.